# Why the AKKA TypedActor class has two methods with the same signature?

Tags: java, akka

In using `TypedActor.get(system)` intellij spell an error 'ambiguous method call', here `system` is of type `ActorSystem`. I found in the decompiled source code of the `TypedActor` class file there are two methods with the same signature:
[image: snapshot]

To my knowledge it is impossible for two methods to have the same signature in Java, so what is wrong here? What is the proper way to call the `TypedActor.get(ActorSystem system)` method?

The version of AKKA I'm using is 2.5.11 and the jar file akka-actor_2.13.0-M3.

Comment: The argument ```system``` is already of type ```ActorSystem```, defined as ```ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("TestSystem")```， the confusion is there are two methods get(ActorSystem system) in TypedActor. @user

Comment: The decompiled Java code shows there are 2 methods with the exact same signature, see the screen shot above, as I don't know Scala I'm not sure if it is so in the original Scala code, maybe it is just an issue of the decompiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: According to @johanandren [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61267665/11882002), this was a bug and it has now been fixed.

You can use
`TypedActor$.MODULE$.get(system)`. This happens because of the way Scala objects get turned into singleton classes.

A Scala object `TypedActor` actually gets turned into the class `TypedActor$` with a singleton instance called `MODULE$`. This is because JVM bytecode doesn't actually support Scala's singleton objects, so lots of Scala names are wrangled and are hard to access from Java.

Comment: Though looks like a hack, ```TypedActor$.MODULE$.get(system)``` do works, no casting needed.

Comment: @Yulin You should probably be using Scala with Akka

Comment: I'm using Java with Akka as I don't know Scala. Another point I don't understand is the class name ends with a $ sign, I found a lot of classes has two versions, one named ```xxx``` and another named ```xxx$```, to my knowledge the dollar notation is only for inner classes as in ```OuterClazz$InnerClazz``` or ```OuterClazz$3``` so will not appear at the end. By the way, the original ```TypedActor.get(system)``` which dose not work is following the offical doc:  https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2/java/typed-actors.html

Answer (score 2):

This was a bug caused by an issue in the Scala compiler (https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/25449) it has since been fixed so upgrading to a more recent Akka version should fix it.